# How to count down large payments with a loop with c#

Tags: c#, countdown

I am trying to make my own countdown of the national debt using loop statements.  I am still very new to programming so I am having a hard time figuring out how to make this loop.  I want to display how long it will take to pay off the debt if $100,000,000 was paid each day.  I would like to display the numbers of days and years, but my priority right now is the loop.  So far I have this

```
namespace Count_Down_The_National_Debt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //step 1
            // use 19.9 trillion dollars 
            long national_debt = 19900000000000;
            // keep track of how many days and it years it takes to pay off the US National Debt
            int day = 0, years = 0;
```

I looked back at a simpler program I made that used loops, but it was for counting up and not down.  This is what I made based on my past program;

```
int j = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("By 100 Millions ");
            while (national_debt > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());
                j = j - 100000000;
            }
```

However, it just runs in an infinite loop until I close my program.  Will I need a break of some kind, or do I need to completely rewrite my loop?

Comment: Are you intentionally ignoring accrued interest during the paydown period?

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Divide: `var totalDays = unimaginablyLargeSum / 100000000;`. On the other hand, an infinite loop has a certain charm in this particular case.

Comment: My question is why wouldn't this be an infinite loop? Clearly the variable `national_debt` doesn't get changed in the loop, so there is no reason why the condition would have changed.

Comment: Yes, I am also ignoring that the debt will be increasing at all during this time (even though I know that that would not happen).

Comment: You are never modifying `national_debt` (ie decreasing it), so your code will just continue to run because `national_debt` will **always** be greater than 0.

Comment: It would not be an infinite loop because I need to stop it once it reaches 0, which I should have included in my answer, I apologize.

Comment: @maccettura, what would be the best way to modify it?

Comment: Also, like @EdPlunkett said. This is just simple division.

Comment: @Thatonepeep I'm assuming you want to do `national_debt = national_debt - 100000000` instead. Modifying `j` is pointless here as it's not being used.

Comment: Or just `national_debt -= 100000000`

Comment: Are you going to display the result of each subtraction or such as that? Otherwise I don't see the point in the loop at all, and would just stick with division.

Comment: Yes, I would like to display the result of each subtraction, which is why I thought it would be best to use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't very good in my opinion.  A while loop that is dependent on incrementing/decrementing numbers usually means you should not use a while loop.  A better way to handle this is to use a `for` loop (and to put it in a method so its resuable)

```
private static void CalculatePayDownDays(long payPerDay, long nationalDebt)
{
    long days = (long)Math.Ceiling((decimal)nationalDebt / payPerDay);

    for (long i = 1; i < days + 1; i++)
    {
        nationalDebt -= payPerDay;
        Console.WriteLine("Day {0}, New Balance: {1:c}", i, nationalDebt);
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iP0vHQ)

**EDIT**

For the pedantic among us, I *slightly* modified the method.

Comment: Okay, but I do have another question based off of that (though it is mainly for clarification purposes.  The CalculatePayDownDays, what makes it so that the program understands what to do? Is it the keyword calculate? I was just wondering so that I could refer back to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I can name the method anything I want, I could call it `IceCream()`, it does not matter.  Look at the code inside `Main()`, see how it calls `CalculatePayDownDays(100000000, nationalDebt);`?  That is what makes it run, _something_ has to call the method

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.  I apologize for not phrasing the question better.  Thank you for your help, and sorry to keep bothering you, but I have one final question.  Would I be able to add year next to day? If so, would I define it as an int or something else?

Comment: I added comments to the fiddle so you can see quick notes on each line.  You can certainly extend it to add years as well, but to do it right would be more complex.  A year is not a whole number of days (its 365.2422), so to do it properly would take more time and knowledge than you currently have now.  If you wanted to do it in the "not entirely accurate" way, you can create another for loop (thats responsbile for the years), and then nest the day for loop inside that.  Think through the logic and try to do it yourself.

Comment: You would only need to modify the contents of the CalculatePayDownDays method.  Honestly I would really look into intro to C# tutorials before heading down this direction.  You could really gain a lot from some C#/programming basics.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would actually use a for loop which can be able to both increment and decrement. For the incrementing for loop, the C# syntax would like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    // Put your logic here
}
```

However, the decrementing loop is a little different.  Using your example:

```
for(long d = national_debt; d > 0; d--)
{
    // Put your logic here
}
```

Hope that this can help you to understand, and potentially lead you to solve your problem.

Comment: This isn't an answer yet.  Your for loop example would not help in anyway

Comment: `d--` doesn't seem quite right, perhaps `d - 100000000`

Answer (score 1):

In general *any* type of loop is not a computationally efficient way to solve this problem because it can be solved with arithmetic as demonstrated later. I assume that you trying to solve it with a while loop as you suggested in the question purely as a learning exercise in while loops. With that said, you will need your loop condition to be dependent on the value you are modifying. In your case you could make it dependent on j, and initialize j to the start value of national_debt. Here is a more complete example using more verbose variable names:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long initial_national_debt = 19900000000000;
            long national_debt = initial_national_debt;
            long payment_size = 100000000;

            while (national_debt > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(national_debt);
                national_debt -= payment_size;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The answer proposed by @maccettura fails to properly calculate the number of days it will take to pay off the debt. For example if the debt is $100 and the payment increment is $200, it takes one day to pay off the debt. However truncating integer division says that 100 / 200 is equal to zero. It clearly does not take zero days to pay off the debt in this scenario.

As I hinted to earlier, this problem can be solved directly. See the following snippet:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long national_debt = 19900000000000;
            long payment_size = 100000000;

            long total_days_to_pay = national_debt / payment_size;

            // if the debt is not evenly divisible by the payment size, then there is one partial day of debt
            if (national_debt % payment_size != 0)
                total_days_to_pay++;

            Console.WriteLine("It takes " + total_days_to_pay + " total days to pay off the national debt.");
            Console.WriteLine("That's " + total_days_to_pay / 365 + " years and " + total_days_to_pay % 365 + " days !");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `while` loop that is dependent on incrementing/decrementing numbers _usually_ means you should not use a while loop...